# Async DataCache API (.NET)

Tags: caching, asynchronous, azure, distributed

I'm using the DataCache API that is part of the Windows Azure Caching Nuget package and I was wondering why there isn't a way to make non-blocking calls against the constituent methods. Am I missing something? I understand that the latencies on these calls are going to be low but it's still a network call - if you're not using the local cache setting.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: The best I could think of is, that, whoever implemented that particular library is not familiar with Async and Tasks.  As shocking as that sounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand why the library is this way then I'd have a read of [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) on exposing async wrappers for synchronous methods.  TL:DR; There are two distinct reasons for wanting to do async, scalability and responsiveness.  You really only need an async version of a method if it will help with the former, the latter you can leave to the consumers of your API because it's easy.

EDIT:  It seems people have missed my intent in this answer, so I'll try adding some more clarification.

Yes, the cache client *may* make a network call and MS are trying to get everyone to make all their network calls in a non-blocking manner so that apps remain responsive.  However this is a cache and it is designed to be very fast.  If you make a request to the cache and the item is not in local cache ([according to Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/09/03/windows-azure-new-distributed-dedicated-high-performance-cache-service-more-cool-improvements.aspx)) the response should take 1ms.  Given that the response is so quick (and if you are using local cache it will be even quicker), they would have likely added more overhead by creating tasks to run it in the background than they would have gained.

Comment: Enhanced scalability is precisely why I'm looking for non-blocking calls against the cache. I don't want my instances spending the bulk of the time waiting for I/O. I understand that it's less of concern when communicating with the cache (as opposed to say, the database) but as I mentioned in my first post, it's still a network call.

Comment: The point of the article was that the implementer of the library couldn't (or just didn't get around to) thinking of a way of implementing that call in a way that would be more scalable if it was async.  If it is still a concern for you, then you can write your own async wrapper as an extension methods pretty simply.  Before going to far down that path though, I would profile your code, adding an async wrapper does add a performance hit that may not be justified in this case.  Particularly if you're using local cache in which case there is no network call.

Comment: @knightpfhor: adding an async wrapper on top of an already synchronous API will not make it better, just worse, as a thread is already being blocked by IO, and you are adding the overhead of context switches, creation of tasks, etc.
What MSDev23 asked is why there is not native async calls in the API that would not block a thread for IO in the first place.

Comment: At no point have I claimed that adding an async wrapper would improve performance, in fact in my comment I say it will add a performance hit I.e. make it worse.  As for why there is no async methods, I thought i'd answered that as well (also in the comment, but should go in the answer), the implementor didn't know how to create a method that made sense in this context.